# SwiftUI Optional TextField

Tags: swiftui

Can SwiftUI Text Fields work with optional Bindings? Currently this code:

```
struct SOTestView : View {
    @State var test: String? = "Test"

    var body: some View {
        TextField($test)
    }
}
```

produces the following error:

> Cannot convert value of type 'Binding< String?>' to expected argument type 'Binding< String>'

Is there any way around this? Using Optionals in data models is a very common pattern - in fact it's the default in Core Data so it seems strange that SwiftUI wouldn't support them

Comment: TextField requires a Binding<String>, not a Binding<String?>. So it seems you cannot. Could you elaborate why you would need such binding?

Comment: I have a Contact NSManaged Object with the property `twitter: String?` that allows the user to optionally associate a Twitter account with the contact using a TextField

Comment: Could you use a null string instead? `@State var test = ""`? If not, then what do you want with the `TextField` when your string is `nil`?

Comment: Yes - the problem is Core Data which creates NSManaged Strings as Optionals

Comment: Well, with `String?` you can argue that `nil` and `""` are "equivalent", but what if your data model contains `CLLocation?` - what is the "equivalent" of `nil`? SwiftUI does not work well with `Optional`, generally.

Comment: Filed a Feedback Assistant report requesting optional bindings, FB7619680.

Comment: Tick Default String for the attribute in the model

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Ultimately the API doesn't allow this - but there is a very simple and versatile workaround:

```
extension Optional where Wrapped == String {
    var _bound: String? {
        get {
            return self
        }
        set {
            self = newValue
        }
    }
    public var bound: String {
        get {
            return _bound ?? ""
        }
        set {
            _bound = newValue.isEmpty ? nil : newValue
        }
    }
}
```

This allows you to keep the optional while making it compatible with Bindings:

```
TextField($test.bound)
```

Comment: This is great as it totally works! 
I feel like there has to be a better way though because `Binding` has an [`optional initializer`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/binding/3115381-init). I just don't know how to use it with the Swift shorthand.

Comment: This is a better answer as it is less verbose.

Comment: This seems like a great solution. Has anyone tried it with other Optionals, like Bool? or Int? or with an enum, like Gender?

Comment: It seems like _bound is not needed. It works when replaced with self.

Answer (score 135):

You can add this operator overload, then it works as naturally as if it wasn't a Binding.

```
func ??<T>(lhs: Binding<Optional<T>>, rhs: T) -> Binding<T> {
    Binding(
        get: { lhs.wrappedValue ?? rhs },
        set: { lhs.wrappedValue = $0 }
    )
}
```

This creates a Binding that returns the left side of the operator's value if it's not nil, otherwise it returns the default value from the right side.

When setting it only sets lhs value, and ignores anything to do with the right hand side.

It can be used like this:

```
TextField("", text: $test ?? "default value")
```

Comment: This is absolutely genius!!! Fantastic solution! I don't understand, why this is not supported by SwiftUI out of the box...

Comment: Where do you write this function?

Comment: @johndoe just as a global function. It's just an operator overload

Comment: @johndoe you create a new swift file with he first line "import SwiftUI" then below that paste his code.

Comment: How come I get a "Invalid redeclaration of '??'" error? I'm using XCode 12.4 with Swift 5.

Comment: I just want to reiterate that this is an amazingly simple and effective solution. Thank you!

Comment: This is great but it should be expressed as a static function within `Binding`.

Comment: @Jessy Why? I'm not sure there's any difference?

Comment: @Jonathan Global operators are Swift 1.x style—functionally equivalent but messy practice. you don't need some archaic "`T`" when `Value` is already defined. `static func ?? (optional: Binding<Value?>, default: Value) -> Self {`

Comment: That's fantastic. Worked as a charm. This should be part of the default way bindings work.

Answer (score 16):

True, at the moment `TextField` in SwiftUI can only be bound to `String` variables, not `String?`.
But you can always define your own `Binding` like so:

```
import SwiftUI

struct SOTest: View {
    @State var text: String?

    var textBinding: Binding<String> {
        Binding<String>(
            get: {
                return self.text ?? ""
        },
            set: { newString in
                self.text = newString
        })
    }

    var body: some View {
        TextField("Enter a string", text: textBinding)
    }
}
```

Basically, you bind the `TextField` text value to this new `Binding<String>` binding, and the binding redirects it to your `String?` @State variable.

Answer (score 5):

I prefer [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61002589/1883707) provided by [@Jonathon.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/191463/jonathan) as it is simple and elegant and provides the coder with an insitu base case when the `Optional` is `.none` (= `nil`) and not `.some`.

However I feel it is worth adding in my two cents here. I learned this technique from reading Jim Dovey's blog on [SwiftUI Bindings with Core Data](https://alanquatermain.me/programming/swiftui/2019-11-15-CoreData-and-bindings/). Its essentially the same answer provided by @Jonathon. but does include a nice pattern that can be replicated for a number of different data types.

First create an extension on `Binding`

```
public extension Binding where Value: Equatable {
    init(_ source: Binding<Value?>, replacingNilWith nilProxy: Value) {
        self.init(
            get: { source.wrappedValue ?? nilProxy },
            set: { newValue in
                if newValue == nilProxy { source.wrappedValue = nil }
                else { source.wrappedValue = newValue }
            }
        )
    }
}
```

Then use in your code like this...

```
TextField("", text: Binding($test, replacingNilWith: String()))
```

or

```
TextField("", text: Binding($test, replacingNilWith: ""))
```

Comment: I like this answer the most! It’s better to understand and gives a more clear way when I’m actually using this extension in a TextField or something else.

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to be creating a new `Binding` every `body` load. Use a custom `ParseableFormatStyle` instead.

```swift
struct OptionalStringParseableFormatStyle: ParseableFormatStyle {

    var parseStrategy: Strategy = .init()

    func format(_ value: String?) -> String {
        value ?? ""
    }

    struct Strategy: ParseStrategy {

        func parse(_ value: String) throws -> String? {
            guard !value.isEmpty else {
                return nil  // How to handle empty/nil is up to the developer.
            }
            return value
        }

    }

}
```

Then use it

```swift
TextField("My Label", value: $myValue, format: OptionalStringParseableFormatStyle())
```

---

### Make It Generic

I prefer to make generic versions of these styles with static conveniences that can work with any type.

```swift
extension Optional {

    struct FormatStyle<Format: ParseableFormatStyle>: ParseableFormatStyle
    where Format.FormatOutput == String, Format.FormatInput == Wrapped {

        let formatter: Format
        let parseStrategy: Strategy<Format.Strategy>

        init(format: Format) {
            self.formatter = format
            self.parseStrategy = .init(strategy: format.parseStrategy)
        }

        func format(_ value: Format.FormatInput?) -> Format.FormatOutput {
            guard let value else { return "" }
            return formatter.format(value)
        }

        struct Strategy<OutputStrategy: ParseStrategy>: ParseStrategy where OutputStrategy.ParseInput == String {

            let strategy: OutputStrategy

            func parse(_ value: String) throws -> OutputStrategy.ParseOutput? {
                guard !value.isEmpty else { return nil }
                return try strategy.parse(value)
            }

        }

    }

}

extension ParseableFormatStyle where FormatOutput == String {

    var optional: Optional<FormatInput>.FormatStyle<Self> { .init(format: self) }

}
```

String does not have a format style as it is redundant in most cases so I make an identity `ParseableFormatStyle`

```
extension String {

    struct FormatStyle: ParseableFormatStyle {

        var parseStrategy: Strategy = .init()

        func format(_ value: String) -> String {
            value
        }

        struct Strategy: ParseStrategy {

            func parse(_ value: String) throws -> String {
                value
            }

        }

    }

}

extension ParseableFormatStyle where Self == String.FormatStyle {

    static var string: Self { .init() }

}

extension ParseableFormatStyle where Self == Optional<String>.FormatStyle<String.FormatStyle> {

    static var optional: Self { .init(format: .string) }

}
```

Now you can use this for any value. Examples:

```swift
TextField("My Label", value: $myStringValue, format: .optional)
TextField("My Label", value: $myStringValue, format: .string.optional)
TextField("My Label", value: $myNumberValue, format: .number.optional)
TextField("My Label", value: $myDateValue, format: .dateTime.optional)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is just a slightly cleaner version of [Jonathan.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/191463/jonathan)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61002589/1883707), rewritten as a static function for `Binding`:

```swift
public extension Binding {
    /// Create a non-optional version of an optional `Binding` with a default value
    /// - Parameters:
    ///   - lhs: The original `Binding<Value?>` (binding to an optional value)
    ///   - rhs: The default value if the original `wrappedValue` is `nil`
    /// - Returns: The `Binding<Value>` (where `Value` is non-optional)
    static func ??(lhs: Binding<Optional<Value>>, rhs: Value) -> Binding<Value> {
        Binding {
            lhs.wrappedValue ?? rhs
        } set: {
            lhs.wrappedValue = $0
        }
    }
}
```

Here's an example of it in action:

```swift
struct TestView: View {
    @State
    var optionalText: String? = nil

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("Type HERE:", text: $optionalText ?? "default value")

            Button {
                print(optionalText)
            } label: {
                Text("Tap Me!")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:** The `optionalText` variable will contain `nil` if the user does not modify the text field. If any modifications are made, a non-`nil` value will be placed into that variable, although the variable's type is still optional.

Answer (score 0):

### Try this works for me with reusable function

```swift
@State private var name: String? = nil
private func optionalBinding<T>(val: Binding<T?>, defaultVal: T)-> Binding<T>{
    Binding<T>(
        get: {
            return val.wrappedValue ?? defaultVal
        },
        set: { newVal in
            val.wrappedValue = newVal
        }
    )
}
// Usage
TextField("", text: optionalBinding(val: $name, defaultVal: ""))
```

Answer (score 0):

*Swift 5.7, iOS 16*

Here are all the useful `Binding` related extensions I've curated or written.

These cover all bases for me - I haven't found any others to be needed.

I hope someone finds them useful.

```
import SwiftUI

/// Shortcut: Binding(get: .., set: ..) -> bind(.., ..)
func bind<T>(_ get: @escaping () -> (T), _ set: @escaping (T) -> () = {_ in}) -> Binding<T> {
    Binding(get: get, set: set)
}

/// Rebind a Binding<T?> as Binding<T> using a default value.
func bind<T>(_ boundOptional: Binding<Optional<T>>, `default`: T) -> Binding<T> {
    Binding(
        get: { boundOptional.wrappedValue ?? `default`},
        set: { boundOptional.wrappedValue = $0 }
    )
}

/// Example: bindConstant(false)
func bind<Wrapped>(constant: Wrapped) -> Binding<Wrapped> { Binding.constant(constant) }

extension Binding {
    
    /// `transform` receives new value before it's been set,
    /// returns updated new value (which is set)
    func willSet(_ transform: @escaping (Value) -> (Value)) -> Binding<Value> {
        Binding(get: { self.wrappedValue },
                set: { self.wrappedValue = transform($0) })
    }

    /// `notify` receives new value after it's been set
    func didSet(_ notify: @escaping (Value) -> ()) -> Binding<Value> {
        Binding(get: { self.wrappedValue },
                set: { self.wrappedValue = $0; notify($0) })
    }
}

/// Example: `TextField("", text: $test ?? "default value")`
/// See https://stackoverflow.com/a/61002589/5970728
func ??<T>(_ boundCollection: Binding<Optional<T>>, `default`: T) -> Binding<T> {
    bind(boundCollection, default: `default`)
}

// Allows use of optional binding where non-optional is expected.
// Example: `Text($myOptionalStringBinding)`
// From: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57041232/5970728
extension Optional where Wrapped == String {
    var _bound: String? {
        get {
            return self
        }
        set {
            self = newValue
        }
    }
    public var bound: String {
        get {
            return _bound ?? ""
        }
        set {
            _bound = newValue.isEmpty ? nil : newValue
        }
    }
}

/// Returns binding for given `keyPath` in given `root` object.
func keyBind<Root, Element>(_ root: Root, keyPath: WritableKeyPath<Root, Element>) -> Binding<Element> {
    var root: Root = root
    return Binding(get: { root[keyPath: keyPath] }, set: { root[keyPath: keyPath] = $0 })
}

/// Bind over a collection (is this inbuilt now? ForEach makes it available)
/// Override `get` and `set` for custom behaviour.
/// Example: `$myCollection.bind(index)`
extension MutableCollection where Index == Int {
    func bind(_ index: Index,
              or defaultValue: Element,
              get: @escaping (Element) -> Element = { $0 }, // (existing value)
              set: @escaping (Self, Index, Element, Element) -> Element = { $3 } // (items, index, old value, new value)
    ) -> Binding<Element> {
        var _self = self
        return Binding(
            get: { _self.indices.contains(index) ? get(_self[index]) : defaultValue },
            set: { if _self.indices.contains(index) { _self.safeset(index, set(_self, index, _self[index], $0)) } }
        )
    }
}
```