# How to assign an optional Binding parameter in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, binding, swiftui

I'm trying to build a custom `NavBar` with some optional `Views`, like a searchbar (but only if the view needs to display it).

I need to pass some `@State` properties with `@Binding` down the views, basically. But I also need them to be `Optional` parameters.

Here's an example:

```swift
struct NavBar: View {
    
    var isSearchable: Bool?
    
    @Binding var searchTxt: String
    @Binding var searchIsOn: Bool
    
    var navBarTitle: String
    var navBarAction: (() -> Void)?
    var navBarImage: String?
    
    init(navBarTitle: String, navBarAction: (() -> Void)? = nil, navBarImage: String? = nil, isSearchable: Bool? = false, searchTxt: (Binding<String>)?, searchIsOn : (Binding<Bool>)?) {
        self.navBarTitle = navBarTitle
        if(navBarAction != nil) {
            self.navBarAction = navBarAction!
        }
        if(navBarImage != nil) {
            self.navBarImage = navBarImage!
        }
        self.isSearchable = isSearchable
        
        self._searchTxt = (searchTxt != nil) ? (searchTxt!).binding : nil
        self._searchIsOn = (searchIsOn != nil) ? (searchIsOn!).binding : nil
        
        assert((navBarAction != nil) ? navBarImage != nil : true)
        assert((isSearchable! == true) ? (searchTxt!.value.count > 0) : true)
    }
// var body ....

}
```

The properties I'm talking about are `searchIsOn` and `searchTxt`.
But doing the assignment `self._searchTxt = searchTxt` or  `self._searchIsOn = searchIsOn` throws a compile error:

> Cannot assign value of type 'Binding?' to type 'Binding'

Do you know how could I resolve this issue?

Or is there a better way to do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: I posted an answer, but I wanted to add one word of constructive criticism: Swift doesn't require semi-colons at the end of a line of code. Most would say if you remove them it's more "Swiftier". :-)

Comment: Correct, and I 100% of the time use them on every return statement.

Answer (score 117, accepted):

```
@Binding var searchTxt: String?

init(searchTxt: Binding<String?>?) {
    self._searchTxt = searchTxt ?? Binding.constant(nil)
}
```

---

Update: I prefer this one. `TextField("", text: $text ?? "default value")`

https://stackoverflow.com/a/61002589/4728060

```
func ??<T>(lhs: Binding<Optional<T>>, rhs: T) -> Binding<T> {
    Binding(
        get: { lhs.wrappedValue ?? rhs },
        set: { lhs.wrappedValue = $0 }
    )
}
```

Comment: You can also use `self._searchTxt = searchTxt ?? Binding.constant(nil)`

Comment: Your answer helped me find a different answer...I've been looking for `Binding.constant("my string")` for ages!! Thank you!!!

Answer (score 44):

What you want is an Optional Binding of a String, not a Binding of an Optional String. I don't think you can achieve that by using the @Binding annotation.

However, you don't need to used the annotation. You can just declare the variable as a Binding:

Your

```
@Binding var searchTxt: String?
```

then turns to this

```
var searchTxt: Binding<String?>
```

But this way the syntax lets you place the ? wherever you want. So if you move it to the end, after the Binding's closing tag, you have what you want.

```
var searchTxt: Binding<String>?
```

If you want to access the String inside your Binding, you have to use the wrappedValue property.

```
Text(searchTxt!.wrappedValue)
```

Answer (score 8):

why not use a default parameter value

```
@Binding var searchTxt: String?

init(searchTxt: Binding<String?> = Binding.constant(nil)) {
    self._searchTxt = searchTxt
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
@Binding var searchTxt: String

init(searchTxt: Binding<String>? = nil) {
    if let searchTxt = searchTxt {
        self._searchTxt = searchTxt
    } else {
        var txt: String = ""
        self._searchTxt = Binding(
            get: { txt },
            set: { txt = $0 }
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I have a `UIViewControllerRepresentable` in order to use `UIImagePickerController`. If you've ever used this image picker, you know that you need to image returned to be an optional. So in my `ContentView` I declared:

```
@State var uiImage: UIImage?

...

if uiImage != nil {
    Image(uiImage: $uiImage)
} else {
    Rectangle()
}
```

And in my `ImagePicker` (that's my `SwiftUI` view) I have:

```
@Binding var uiImage: UIImage?
```

Works like a charm.

(The `if` statement is pretty much psuedo-code, as I'm actually using an `MTKView` and a `CIImage`, but your get the drift - you use the optional just as you would anywhere else.)

Comment: My problem is that if I use your method with a custom `init()`, the `Binding` parameter becomes `Binding<Type?>` and not `(Binding<Type>)?`, so not optional anymore. So, when declaring the `View` struct that contains this type of variable, I need to specify the `Binding`. I want it to be fully optional.

Answer (score 1):

So below is example to use optional Binding and how to access the binding and toggle to show some view:

```
struct NavBar: View {
    @Binding var showUser: Bool
    var showOptional: Binding<Bool>?
    
    var body: some View {
    
    VStack {
     Button(action: { showUser.toggle() },
            label: { Text("NOT OPTIONAL") })
    
     Button(action: { showSelectBuddy?.wrappedValue.toggle()) },
            label: { Text("NOT OPTIONAL") })
    
    }
    }
    }

    struct UseNavbar: View {
    
    @State var showoptional = false
    @State var show = false 
    
    var body: some View {
    Text("Optional")
    .navigationBarItems(leading:
    NavBar(showUser: show), trailing: NavBar(showUser: show, showOptional: showoptional))
    }
    }
```