# Binding an Optional

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am given an optional date, and would like the ability to display a date picker for it.

```swift
import SwiftUI


struct ContentView: View {
    @State var someDate: Date?

    var body: some View {
        OptionalDate(date: $someDate)
    }
}

struct OptionalDate: View {
    @Binding var date: Date?

    var body: some View {

        if date == nil {
            return Text("No date").onTapGesture {
                self.date = Date()   // start picking!
            }
        } else {
            return DatePicker(selection: $date, displayedComponents: .date) {
                Text("Due Date")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
Cannot convert value of type 'Binding<Date?>' to expected argument type 'Binding<Date>'
```

Not to mention I'm going to have to figure out the opaque view...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to assign an optional Binding parameter in SwiftUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57163055/how-to-assign-an-optional-binding-parameter-in-swiftui)

Answer (score 5):

**iOS 13**

Custom bindings are your friends! Also, for conditional views you can always use `Group`, that will make your life much easier and will resolve the `Opaque` issue as it will always be considered as a `Group` whatever you have as a subview.

```
struct OptionalDateView: View {
    
    @Binding var date: Date?

    var body: some View {
        Group {
            if date == nil {
                Text("No date").onTapGesture {
                    self.date = Date()
                }
            } else {
                DatePicker(selection: dateBinding, displayedComponents: .date) {
                    Text("Due Date")
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    private var dateBinding: Binding<Date> {
        Binding(get: {
            self.date ?? Date()
        }, set: {
            self.date = $0
        })
    }
}
```

**iOS 14**

```
struct OptionalDateView: View {
    
    @Binding var date: Date?

    var body: some View {
        if date == nil {
            Text("No date").onTapGesture {
                date = Date()
            }
        } else {
            DatePicker(selection: dateBinding, displayedComponents: .date) {
                Text("Due Date")
            }
        }
    }
    
    private var dateBinding: Binding<Date> {
        Binding {
            date ?? Date()
        } set: {
            date = $0
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Huh! Neat. So this basically forces the binding to unwrap the optional when it is `gotten`? Where can I learn more?

Comment: This is just a wrapper around `Binding`. So, it basically creates a new `Binding` which returns `self.date!` when asked and calls `self.date = $0` when a new value is set. If we didn't create this binding and passed `$date`, it would work like this: `Binding(get: { self.date, set: { self.date = $0 })` which was creating the problem as `self.date` is optional. Have a look at here: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-create-custom-bindings

Comment: I notice you can't do `private var dateBinding = Binding(get: {...` because you can't reference other properties? But you can if you return it from a custom getter? Weird!

Comment: @speg no, it's just you can't use `self` when you define a variable as `self` is not initialized yet. But when you use `computed property`, you can use `self` as computed properties are called after the object (`struct` in this case) is initialized.