# Optional Binding in parameter SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

Here are my optional binding

```
@Binding var showSheetModifFile : Bool?
@Binding var fileToModify : File?

init( showSheetModifFile : Binding<Bool?>? = nil, fileToModify : Binding<File?>? = nil) {
    _showSheetModifFile = showSheetModifFile ?? Binding.constant(nil)
    _fileToModify = fileToModify ?? Binding.constant(nil)
}
```

So now when I try to call this constructor:

```
@State var showModifFileSheet : Bool? = false
@State var fileToModify : File? = File()
...

SingleFileView(showSheetModifFile: self.$showModifFileSheet, fileToModify: self.$fileToModify)
```

I got this error:

> 'Binding<Bool?>' is not convertible to 'Binding<Bool?>?'

Comment: This question is similar: [How to assign an optional Binding parameter in SwiftUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57163055/how-to-assign-an-optional-binding-parameter-in-swiftui)

Comment: Yes but the accepted answer doesn't show how to call the constructor

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is special Binding constructor for this purpose

```
SingleFileView(showSheetModifFile: Binding(self.$showModifFileSheet), 
   fileToModify: Binding(self.$fileToModify))
```

Update: alternate solution

```
struct FileDemoView: View {
    @State var showModifFileSheet : Bool? = false
    @State var fileToModify : File? = File()

    var body: some View {
        SingleFileView(showSheetModifFile: $showModifFileSheet, fileToModify: $fileToModify)
    }

}


struct SingleFileView: View {
    @Binding var showSheetModifFile : Bool?
    @Binding var fileToModify : File?


    init(showSheetModifFile : Binding<Bool?> = .constant(nil), fileToModify : Binding<File?> = .constant(nil)) {
        _showSheetModifFile = showSheetModifFile
        _fileToModify = fileToModify
    }

    var body: some View {
        Text("")
    }
}
```

Comment: i still have the error : Cannot convert value of type 'Binding<Bool>?' to expected argument type 'Binding<Bool?>?'

Comment: @SofianeLyno Is your init taking `Binding<Bool?>?` perhaps?