# How to convert Binding<String?> to Binding<String> in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui

How to convert Binding<String?> to Binding in SwiftUI

variable declared as:

```
@Binding var name: String?
```

Comment: SwiftUI relies on non-optional values much more than UIKit. Do you really need the optional? And unlike regular properties a `Binding` can (even should) be declared without a default value.

Answer (score 2):

It depends where do you use it, but most probably, you'd need something, like

```
Binding(name) ?? .constant("")
```

In some cases it might be needed proxy binding created in place, like in https://stackoverflow.com/a/59274498/12299030.

For scenarios with arguments you can use approach like in https://stackoverflow.com/a/62217832/12299030.

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own `Binding Extension` with default values for cases in where `Value` is `Optional`.

### Swift 5 Extension

```
extension Binding where Value: Equatable {
    
    
    /// Given a binding to an optional value, creates a non-optional binding that projects
    /// the unwrapped value. If the given optional binding contains `nil`, then the supplied
    /// value is assigned to it before the projected binding is generated.
    ///
    /// This allows for one-line use of optional bindings, which is very useful for CoreData types
    /// which are non-optional in the model schema but which are still declared nullable and may
    /// be nil at runtime before an initial value has been set.
    ///
    ///     class Thing: NSManagedObject {
    ///         @NSManaged var name: String?
    ///     }
    ///     struct MyView: View {
    ///         @State var thing = Thing(name: "Bob")
    ///         var body: some View {
    ///             TextField("Name", text: .bind($thing.name, ""))
    ///         }
    ///     }
    ///
    /// - note: From experimentation, it seems that a binding created from an `@State` variable
    /// is not immediately 'writable'. There is seemingly some work done by SwiftUI following the render pass
    /// to make newly-created or assigned bindings modifiable, so simply assigning to
    /// `source.wrappedValue` inside `init` is not likely to have any effect. The implementation
    /// has been designed to work around this (we don't assume that we can unsafely-unwrap even after
    /// assigning a non-`nil` value), but a side-effect is that if the binding is never written to outside of
    /// the getter, then there is no guarantee that the underlying value will become non-`nil`.
    @available(macOS 10.15, iOS 13, tvOS 13, watchOS 6, *)
    static func bindOptional(_ source: Binding<Value?>, _ defaultValue: Value) -> Binding<Value> {
        self.init(get: {
            source.wrappedValue ?? defaultValue
        }, set: {
            source.wrappedValue = ($0 as? String) == "" ? nil : $0
        })
    }
}
```

### Usage

```
struct ContentView: View { 
    @Binding var title: String?

    var body: some View { 
        TextField("Title Value", text: .bindOptional($title, "Default Title"))
    }
}
```