# Optional chaining the binding value in SwiftUI textfield

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have the following model:

```
struct Food: Codable, Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var name: String = ""
    var energy: Float?
    var water: Float?
    var macroProfile: MacronutrientProfile?
}

struct MacronutrientProfile: Codable {
    var carb: Float?
    var protein: Float?
    var fat: Float?
}
```

I am trying to bind values of an instance of this model to `TextField` as such:

```
struct FoodEditView: View {
    @State var food: Food
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Section(header: Text("Basics").fontWeight(.bold)) {
                HStack {
                    Text("Name")
                    Spacer()
                    TextField("Name", text: $food.name)
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.trailing)
                }
                HStack {
                    Text("Energy")
                    Spacer()
                    TextField("Calories", value: $food.energy, formatter: calorie)
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.trailing)
                    .keyboardType(.numberPad)
                }
                HStack {
                    Text("Water")
                    Spacer()
                    TextField("Grams", value: $food.water, formatter: gram)
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.trailing)
                    .keyboardType(.numberPad)
                }
            }
            .textCase(.none)
            Section(header: Text("Macronutrients").fontWeight(.bold)) {
                HStack {
                    Text("Carbohydrates")
                    Spacer()
                    TextField("Grams", value: $food.macroProfile?.carb, formatter: gram)
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.trailing)
                    .keyboardType(.numberPad)
                }
                HStack {
                    Text("Protein")
                    Spacer()
                    TextField("Grams", value: $food.macroProfile?.protein, formatter: gram)
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.trailing)
                    .keyboardType(.numberPad)
                }
                HStack {
                    Text("Fat")
                    Spacer()
                    TextField("Grams", value: $food.macroProfile?.fat, formatter: gram)
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.trailing)
                    .keyboardType(.numberPad)
                }
            }
            .textCase(.none)
```

I am this rather strange, long list of errors when chaining `macroProfile`:

[image: XCode Error]

My question is, how is it that I am getting these errors when optional chaining `macroProfile` and not when using `energy` or `water`, both of which are also optional values? And what is the best approach to fix this?

Comment: Use custom binding : https://stackoverflow.com/a/59642601/14733292

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When use the "dot chaining" syntax on a `Binding` its a shortcut syntax for creating a `Binding`. It doesn't have the same semantics "lookup a property of this thing" that the dot syntax usually holds.

So `$food.name` is **not** going to resolve the binding of `food` then reference one of its properties.  It going to create a two-way `Binding<String>` to the `name` property of the food.

Similarly, when you have `$food.macroProfile` the value of that expression is a `Binding<MacroNutrientProfile?>`... a binding that will directly change a value in `food` (and the value it can change is an optional).  It is **not** a resolution of the binding `$food` followed by referencing one of that object's properties.

`$food.macroProfile?.carb` is nonsensical because `$food.macroProfile` is of type `Binding<MacroNutrientProfile?>` which is not an optional type.  So you see errors.

`$food.name` is not nonsensical because it is a `Binding<String>` and you're not trying to treat a non-optional value as an optional.

One way to change it is to use a custom binding:

```
struct Food: Codable, Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var name: String = ""
    var energy: Float?
    var water: Float?
    var macroProfile: MacronutrientProfile?
}

struct MacronutrientProfile: Codable {
    var carb: Float?
    var protein: Float?
    var fat: Float?
}

struct SomeView : View {
    @State var food: Food
    let gram = NumberFormatter()

    var body : some View {
        let carbBinding = Binding<Float?>(get: { food.macroProfile?.carb },
                                          set: { newValue in food.macroProfile?.carb = newValue })

        return HStack {
           Text("Carbohydrates")
           Spacer()
            TextField("Grams", value: carbBinding, formatter: gram)
           .multilineTextAlignment(.trailing)
           .keyboardType(.numberPad)
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Very informative. That answers the first part of my question. Now, how do I fix it?

Comment: I've added a code sample demonstrating one way.

Comment: is there really no better way to do this? This feels a bit cumbersome. If my food model gets bigger, I have to create a custom binding for each nested object.

Comment: I don't think there can be a better way to do this without changing the compiler. What Scott wrote is essentially a kind of `map` function with bidirectionality; you could write an extension to add `Binding.map` but it wouldn't save you much over using `Binding`'s initializer. There would need to be a change to the compiler to do this automatically with `?`, or it might be possible to do something with Swift's new macro system to add sugar for this.

Comment: @Awesome-o Apple already added a macro-based implementation of Observation which does better with nested observables.  without trying I don’t know it fixes this specific problem, but it’s worth a try.