# How should I bind to a Core Data Entity String Attribute within a SwiftUI view?

Tags: swift, core-data, swiftui

Here is my SwiftUI view:

```
struct EditEntity: View {
    @State var entity: Entity
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            TextField("Entity Name", text: $entity.name)
        }
    }
}
```

`Entity` is an object Core Data is creating for me using code generation.

And here is how that entity is set up in the Core Data model file:

[image: Core Data model setup]

And the issue I am having is that `$entity.name` is a `Binding<String?>` object, when SwiftUI wants a `Binding<String>` object. So I am getting this compile error:

`Cannot convert value of type 'Binding<String?>' to expected argument type 'Binding<String>'`

So does anyone know what the best practise is for this? Should I create a seperate non-optional variable within the view class for the attribute? As can be seen in my screenshot, I set the attribute to not be optional in the hope it would be a non-optional string, but clearly that didn't work.

I found essentially this question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57021722/swiftui-optional-textfield). And the answer there is to create an extension. Is this really what needs to be done when trying to use SwiftUI with Core Data together to do such a basic thing?

Answer (score 4):

The following should help:

```
TextField("Entity Name", text: Binding($entity.name)!)
```

Answer (score 3):

I learned this technique from reading Jim Dovey's blog on [SwiftUI Bindings with Core Data](https://alanquatermain.me/programming/swiftui/2019-11-15-CoreData-and-bindings/). It includes a nice pattern that can be replicated for a number of different data types.

First create an extension on `Binding`

```
public extension Binding where Value: Equatable {
    init(_ source: Binding<Value?>, replacingNilWith nilProxy: Value) {
        self.init(
            get: { source.wrappedValue ?? nilProxy },
            set: { newValue in
                if newValue == nilProxy { source.wrappedValue = nil }
                else { source.wrappedValue = newValue }
            }
        )
    }
}
```

Then use in your code like this...

```
TextField("Entity Name", text: Binding($entity.name, replacingNilWith: ""))
```

This is based upon the fact that in your Core Data model editor, you keep your `Entity` attribute `name` as `Optional` (checked).