# How to implement a List of TextFields in SwiftUI without breaking deletion

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

When I

1. Create a Master-Detail App in XCode
2. Use Core Data
3. Add a new field to the Event Model (say `title` as `String`)
4. Change the `MasterView` implementation to this

```
struct MasterView: View {
    @FetchRequest(
        sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Event.timestamp, ascending: true)], 
        animation: .default)
    var events: FetchedResults<Event>

    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext)
    var viewContext

    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(events, id: \.self) { event in
                NavigationLink(
                    destination: DetailView(event: event)
                ) {
                    TextField("Title", text: Binding(ObservedObject<Event>(wrappedValue: event).projectedValue.title)!)
                }
            }.onDelete { indices in
                self.events.delete(at: indices, from: self.viewContext)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

, i.e., swap out the `Text` for `TextField` with an appropriate binding to the `title` attribute of the `event` object, XCode happily compiles and the app runs with the expected behaviour as long as I don't try to delete from the List.

The moment I try to delete an `Event`, it crashes with this stacktrace

```
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)
    #0: [33m`SwiftUI.BindingOperations.ForceUnwrapping.get(base: Swift.Optional<A>) -> A[0m
    #1: [33m`protocol witness for SwiftUI.Projection.get(base: A.Base) -> A.Projected in conformance SwiftUI.BindingOperations.ForceUnwrapping<A> : SwiftUI.Projection in SwiftUI[0m
    #2: [33m`SwiftUI.(ProjectedLocation in _5A9440699EF65619D724050F1A6941EE).update(context: AttributeGraph.AttributeContext<SwiftUI.VoidAttribute>, state: inout Swift.Optional<Any>) -> (B.Projected, Swift.Bool)[0m
    #3: [33m`SwiftUI.LocationBox.update(context: AttributeGraph.AttributeContext<SwiftUI.VoidAttribute>, state: inout Swift.Optional<Any>) -> (A.Value, Swift.Bool)[0m
    #4: [33m`SwiftUI.Binding.(ScopedLocation in _5436F2B399369BE3B016147A5F8FE9F2).update(context: AttributeGraph.AttributeContext<SwiftUI.VoidAttribute>, state: inout Swift.Optional<Any>) -> (A, Swift.Bool)[0m
    #5: [33m`protocol witness for SwiftUI.Location.update(context: AttributeGraph.AttributeContext<SwiftUI.VoidAttribute>, state: inout Swift.Optional<Any>) -> (A.Value, Swift.Bool) in conformance SwiftUI.Binding<A>.(ScopedLocation in _5436F2B399369BE3B016147A5F8FE9F2) : SwiftUI.Location in SwiftUI[0m
    #6: [33m`SwiftUI.LocationBox.update(context: AttributeGraph.AttributeContext<SwiftUI.VoidAttribute>, state: inout Swift.Optional<Any>) -> (A.Value, Swift.Bool)[0m
    #7: [33m`SwiftUI.Binding.(Box in _5436F2B399369BE3B016147A5F8FE9F2).update(property: inout SwiftUI.Binding<A>, context: AttributeGraph.AttributeContext<SwiftUI.VoidAttribute>) -> Swift.Bool[0m
    #8: [33m`static SwiftUI.(BoxVTable in _68550FF604D39F05971FE35A26EE75B0).update(ptr: Swift.UnsafeMutableRawPointer, property: Swift.UnsafeMutableRawPointer, context: AttributeGraph.AttributeContext<SwiftUI.VoidAttribute>) -> Swift.Bool[0m
    #9: [33m`SwiftUI._DynamicPropertyBuffer.update(container: Swift.UnsafeMutableRawPointer, context: AttributeGraph.AttributeContext<SwiftUI.VoidAttribute>) -> Swift.Bool[0m
    #10: [33m`SwiftUI.(DynamicPropertyBody in _9F92ACD17B554E8AB7D29ABB1E796415).update(context: inout AttributeGraph.AttributeContext<SwiftUI.(DynamicPropertyBody in _9F92ACD17B554E8AB7D29ABB1E796415)<A>>) -> ()[0m
    #11: [33m`protocol witness for static AttributeGraph.UntypedAttribute._update(_: Swift.UnsafeMutableRawPointer, graph: __C.AGGraphRef, attribute: __C.AGAttribute) -> () in conformance SwiftUI.(DynamicPropertyBody in _9F92ACD17B554E8AB7D29ABB1E796415)<A> : AttributeGraph.UntypedAttribute in SwiftUI[0m
    #12: [33m`partial apply forwarder[0m
    #13: [33m`AG::Graph::UpdateStack::update[0m
    #14: [33m`AG::Graph::update_attribute[0m
    #15: [33m`AG::Subgraph::update[0m
    #16: [33m`SwiftUI.ViewGraph.(runTransaction in _D63C4EB7F2B205694B6515509E76E98B)(in: __C.AGGraphRef) -> ()[0m
    #17: [33m`closure #1 (__C.AGGraphRef) -> (prefs: Swift.Bool, idealSize: Swift.Bool, outputs: SwiftUI.ViewGraph.Outputs) in SwiftUI.ViewGraph.updateOutputs(at: SwiftUI.Time) -> ()[0m
    #18: [33m`SwiftUI.ViewGraph.updateOutputs(at: SwiftUI.Time) -> ()[0m
    #19: [33m`closure #1 () -> () in closure #1 () -> () in (extension in SwiftUI):SwiftUI.ViewRendererHost.render(interval: Swift.Double, updateDisplayList: Swift.Bool) -> ()[0m
    #20: [33m`closure #1 () -> () in (extension in SwiftUI):SwiftUI.ViewRendererHost.render(interval: Swift.Double, updateDisplayList: Swift.Bool) -> ()[0m
    #21: [33m`(extension in SwiftUI):SwiftUI.ViewRendererHost.render(interval: Swift.Double, updateDisplayList: Swift.Bool) -> ()[0m
    #22: [33m`closure #1 () -> () in SwiftUI._UIHostingView.requestImmediateUpdate() -> ()[0m
    #23: [33m`reabstraction thunk helper from @escaping @callee_guaranteed () -> () to @escaping @callee_unowned @convention(block) () -> ()[0m
    #24: [33m`_dispatch_call_block_and_release[0m
    #25: [33m`_dispatch_client_callout[0m
    #26: [33m`_dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF[0m
    #27: [33m`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__[0m
    #28: [33m`__CFRunLoopRun[0m
    #29: [33m`CFRunLoopRunSpecific[0m
    #30: [33m`GSEventRunModal[0m
    #31: [33m`UIApplicationMain[0m
  * #32: [33m`main[0m at AppDelegate.swift:13
    #33: [33m`start[0m
```

I have tried this: [SwiftUI holding reference to deleted core data object causing crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59123439/swiftui-holding-reference-to-deleted-core-data-object-causing-crash) but to no avail. I have also tried extracting the textfield into a separate view class and using the appropriate propertywrappers.

I suppose I am misusing the infrastructure (binding, observableobject, etc.) somehow. How am I supposed to use these to achieve textfields in a list?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Instead of

> TextField("Title", text: Binding(ObservedObject(wrappedValue:
> event).projectedValue.title)!)

Use

```
TextField("Title", text: Binding<String>(
                   get: {event.title ?? "<none>"}, set: {event.title = $0}))
```

Tested & Works with Xcode 11.2, iOS 13.2

Comment: this is just simple transparent wrapper with explicitly controlled optional

Answer (score 2):

Some ideas on this:

**Option 1**
***(Inline Binding)***

(I'm guessing that there might be a cleaner implementation, but this code works fine)

```
// Somewhere in MasterView...
// A function that returns a binding for the title of an event
func titleBindingFor(_ event: Event) -> Binding<String> {
    Binding<String>(get: { () -> String in
        event.title ?? ""
    }) { (title) in
        event.title = title
    }
}
```

then

```
// Bind it to the textfield
TextField("Title", text: self.titleBindingFor(event))
```

---

**Option 2**
***(Separate View)***

```
extension Optional where Wrapped == String {
    var safe: String {
        get { self ?? "" }
        set { self = newValue }
    }
}

struct TitleEditor: View {
    @ObservedObject var event: Event

    var body: some View {
        TextField("Title", text: $event.title.safe)
    }
}
```

then

```
TitleEditor(event: event)
```

**Note:** I also had to handle the optional timestamp force unwrap (really Apple?!) in DetailView cause I was getting crashes on deletion:

```
struct DetailView: View {
    @ObservedObject var event: Event

    var body: some View {
        let timestamp = event.timestamp ?? Date()
        return Text("\(timestamp, formatter: dateFormatter)")
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Detail"))
    }
}
```

Notice that I'm returning an empty string if the title is nil, which is handled gracefully by the textfield (it shows the placeholder on newly created items)