# Unwrapping optional bindings safely

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

Suppose I have a Model structure like this:

```
struct Model: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var data: String
}
```

It simply contains data and an `id` field, which I see the Apple SwiftUI examples commonly do.

In a ViewModel class, I have this:

```
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var models: [Model] = []
    @Published var modelSelection = Set<Model.ID>()
}
```

I use it like this:

```
List(viewModel.models, selection: $viewModel.modelSelection)
```

Now I have a `DetailView`, which basically displays & modifies the first selected model via a `Binding`.

In order to do this, it must get the first selected models id, and then find that model in `ViewModel.models`. So I created a subscript property in `ViewModel`:

```
subscript(_ modelID: Model.ID) -> Model? {
    get {
        models.first(where: { $0.id == modelID })
    }
    set {
        guard let index = models.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == modelID }) else { return }
        if let newValue = newValue {
            models[index] = newValue
        }
        else {
            models.remove(at: index)
        }
    }
}
```

Now here's `DetailView`. It simply is a `TextField` that modifies the first selected Model:

```
struct DetailView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject private var viewModel: ViewModel

    var body: some View {
        if let id = viewModel.modelSelection.first,
           viewModel[id] != nil,
           let binding = Binding($viewModel[id]) {
            VStack { // VStack is important! It only crashes if VStack is enclosing.
                TextField("", text: binding.data)
            }
        }
        else {
            Text("No (or multiple) Selection")
        }
    }
}
```

The problem comes when I try to remove the currently selected model. I crash with an error in:

```
BindingOperations.ForceUnwrapping.get(base:)
```

The crash only happens with an enclosing `VStack` in DetailView.

I think this crash happens because SwiftUI is referencing the `binding` local variable which contains an `id` that has now been invalidated/removed (or it doesn't update `DetailView.body`, and continues using the old binding).

Here's the full MRE code. To get the crash, select an item from the sidebar, and then press remove.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject private var viewModel = ViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(viewModel.models, selection: $viewModel.modelSelection) { model in
                Text(model.data)
            }
            
            Button("Remove Currently Selected") {
                // Note: I'm not talking about this part unwrapping.
                viewModel[viewModel.modelSelection.first!] = nil
            }
            
            DetailView(viewModel: viewModel)
        }
    }
}

struct Model: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var data: String
}
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var models: [Model] = [Model(data: "Hi"), Model(data: "Bye")]
    @Published var modelSelection = Set<Model.ID>()
    
    subscript(_ modelID: Model.ID) -> Model? {
        get {
            models.first(where: { $0.id == modelID })
        }
        set {
            guard let index = models.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == modelID }) else { return }
            if let newValue = newValue {
                models[index] = newValue
            }
            else {
                models.remove(at: index)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct DetailView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ViewModel

    var body: some View {
        if let id = viewModel.modelSelection.first,
           viewModel[id] != nil,
           let binding = Binding($viewModel[id]) {
            VStack {
                TextField("", text: binding.data)
            }
        }
        else {
            Text("No (or multiple) Selection")
        }
    }
}
```

I was just wondering what is the best way to handle a situation like this (Models with ID's and accessing them with bindings).

I see that in the [WWDC 2021 SwiftUI Garden App](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10289/) example code, instead of returning an optional from the subscript in `ViewModel`, they just force unwrap or return a placeholder object.

However, returning a placeholder object seems meh because in the actual Model I have 10+ fields.

Is there any other way?

**Edit:**
After seeing the answers on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63958106/exception-when-setting-an-optional-binding-to-nil-in-swiftui-after-checking) post and [also this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59270505/how-to-implement-a-list-of-textfields-in-swiftui-without-breaking-deletion), it seems like the best way is to simply use a placeholder.

Comment: I would look into adding a property for the model data to your view model that is either set to the value of `data` for the currently selected model or "" if no model is selected and then use this property instead in your view. This also mean you can remove the ugly `if` from your detail view since you never have an optional to deal with in the view.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I think this is similar to the Apple method. I will try this out, thanks for the suggestion!