# SwiftUI list references deleted NSManagedObjects

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swiftui

When using @FetchRequest to populate a List, SwiftUI will attempt to access a deleted NSManagedObject even after it has been deleted from the store (for example, via swipe action).

This bug is very common and easy to reproduce: simply create a new Xcode project with the default SwiftUI + CoreData template.  Then replace ContentView with this code:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var moc
    @FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: []) private var items: FetchedResults<Item>
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(items) { item in
                ItemRow(item: item)
            }
            .onDelete {
                $0.map{items[$0]}.forEach(moc.delete)
                try! moc.save()
            }
        }
        .toolbar {
            Button("Add") {
                let newItem = Item(context: moc)
                newItem.timestamp = Date()
                try! moc.save()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ItemRow: View {
    @ObservedObject var item: Item
    var body: some View {
        Text("\(item.timestamp!)")
    }
}
```

Add a few items to the list, then swipe to delete a row: the app will crash.  An `ItemRow` is attempting to draw with the now-deleted `Item`.

[A common workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59123439/swiftui-holding-reference-to-deleted-core-data-object-causing-crash) is to wrap the whole subview in a fault check:

```swift
struct ItemRow: View {
    @ObservedObject var item: Item
    var body: some View {
        if !item.isFault {
            Text("\(item.timestamp!)")
        }
    }
}
```

But this is a poor solution and has side effects (objects can be faults when not deleted).

[This answer](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/668299) suggests that wrapping the deletion in `viewContext.perform{}` would work, but the crash still occurs for me.

Any better solutions/workarounds out there?

Comment: I can't replicate this. I'm on Xcode 14.0 beta, but I've used similar techniques in Xcode 13 without issue.

Comment: @ScottM that's very interesting - I'm testing on Xcode 14 right now. Have been seeing the same issue since SwiftUI 1.0 on Xcode 11.

Comment: @ScottM just to be sure: are you testing on iOS?

Comment: Yes I am. I'm actually working on a brand new app right now – I've been keeping the `Item` list view around while I add my own objects and views as a baseline, so if it works when my own code doesn't I've got a comparison. And this deletion code works for me!

Comment: And you're passing Item as @ObservedObject just like my code? That's the important distinction... I'd love to find out what's different about our environments.

Comment: Ah found the discrepancy – i'd tweaked my code to get rid of the force unwrap on `timestamp!` which is where your code crashes (unless you check `isFault` as you have done). Switching to a `swipeAction` to initiate the delete operation at the row level, rather than as a bulk operation, works though.

Answer (score 1):

This does seem to be the result of the `ObservedObject` switching to a fault as part of the delete operation, while `timestamp!` is force unwrapped. The force unwrap works for the full object but not the fault.

An approach which does seem to work is to remove the `.onDelete` action at the `ForEach` level, and replace it with a `swipeAction` at the row level:

```swift
ForEach(items) { item in
  ItemRow(item: item)
    .swipeActions {
      Button("Delete", role: .destructive) {
        viewContext.delete(item)
        try? viewContext.save()
      }
    }
}
```

In any respect, it shows that even with a simple NSManagedObject like `Item`, relying on force unwrapping of attributes comes with risks.

Comment: That's definitely a better workaround than the others I've seen. Still - it's unfortunate that this hasn't been resolved by now. Even the engineers at WWDC recommend implicitly unwrapping NSManagedObject properties to work with Swift.