# Binding<String?> on the SwiftUI View TextField

Tags: swiftui

I have the following view model:

```
struct RegistrationViewModel {

    var firstname: String?
}
```

I want to bind the firstname property in the TextField as shown below:

```
 TextField("First name", text: $registrationVM.firstname)
                      .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
```

I keep getting an error that Binding is not allowed.

Comment: `@State var firstname: String = ""`

Answer (score 1):

To bind objects your variable needs to conform to one of the new wrappers `@State`, `@Binding`, `@ObservableObject`, etc.

Because your `RegistrationViewModel` doesn't conform to `View` the only way to do it is to have your `RegistrationViewModel` conform to `ObservableObject`.

```
class RegistrationViewModel: ObservableObject {

    @Published var firstname: String?
}
```

Once that is done you can call it `View` using

```
@ObservedObject var resgistrationVM: RegistrationViewModel = RegistrationViewModel()
```

or as an `@EnvironmentObject`

https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/handling-user-input

Also, SwiftUI does not work well with optionals but an `extension` can handle that very easily.

[SwiftUI Optional TextField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57021722/swiftui-optional-textfield)

```
extension Optional where Wrapped == String {
    var _bound: String? {
        get {
            return self
        }
        set {
            self = newValue
        }
    }
    public var bound: String {
        get {
            return _bound ?? ""
        }
        set {
            _bound = newValue.isEmpty ? nil : newValue
        }
    }
}
```