# Core Data object binding values - cannot find '$item' in scope

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swiftui

I'm trying to bind a text field value to a core data object and I am getting a `Cannot find '$draft' in scope` error. I've tried moving the `draft` declaration out of `body`, adding `@State let` and `@State var` to the declaration as well, only to get another error thrown at me saying I can't use property wrappers on local properties.

Is there a correct way to do this?

```
struct AddItemView: View {
  @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc
  @Environment (\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
              
  var body: some View {
    @State let draft = Item(context: moc)

    NavigationView {
      HStack {
        TextField("Title", text: $draft.title)
      }
    }
    .navigationTitle(Text("Add an Item"))
  }
}
```

Comment: Where do you call this view from? Why do you need NavigationView if you don't navigate  anywhere from here?

Comment: @Asperi it's a modal view with a title, I just removed most of the irrelevant code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, let's separate it a bit... and all becomes working

```
struct AddItemView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc
    @Environment (\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
                
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NewItemEditor(draft: Item(context: moc))
        }
        .navigationTitle(Text("Add an Item"))
    }
}

struct NewItemEditor: View {
    @ObservedObject var draft: Item
                
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            TextField("Title", text: $draft.title)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: wow... thanks! just one thing to note: I get an error because draft.title is an optional and the TextField can't take those. I used the extension here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/57041232/9710979) to make it work