# How to unwrap an optional @State to be used in a call to something requiring a Binding in swiftui

Tags: swift, swiftui

How do you unwrap an optional @State to be used as a binding parameter?

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var testString = "Hello"
    var body: some View {
        TestView(test: testString)
    }
}

struct TestView : View {
    @State var test : String?
    var body: some View {
       TextField("Test", text: $test)
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Here is the compiler error I receive on the TextField call.

```
Cannot convert value of type 'Binding<String?>' to expected argument type 'Binding<String>'
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57021722/swiftui-optional-textfield

Comment: Your question looks incorrect, did you mean for testString in ContentView to be optional and test in TestView to be declared as @Binding and not @State?

Answer (score 1):

In such case we should use `Binding`

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var testString = "Hello"
    var body: some View {
        TestView(test: $testString)
    }
}

struct TestView : View {
    @Binding var test : String
    var body: some View {
       TextField("Test", text: $test)
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, but I need the argument to be optional to the TestView.

Comment: Scenario shown in question did not depict that, you have to provide more realistic code if you want exact answer. Note, reference provided by @cora gives many possible variants to be adapted with this answer to avoid duplications.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the one line solution which appears to work.

```
TextField("Test", text: Binding($test)!)
```

So new struct is like this

```
struct TestView : View {
    @State var test : String?
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("Test", text: Binding($test)!)
            Text(test!)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And what is the value of testString in ContentView once you have entered some text in the text field in this view?

Comment: The value in ContentView will not change, but that was fine in my example. I was just trying to get an optional passed in to be used in another view that needs a binding value.