# TextField binding to optional number

Tags: swiftui, binding, uitextfield, option-type

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var data: Double?
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("",
                      value: $data,
                      formatter: NumberFormatter(),
                      prompt:Text("..."))
                .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
            Button{
                if let _ = data {
                    //...
                }
            }label:{
                Text("send data").foregroundColor(data == nil ? .gray : .black)
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

I would like to have a textfield:

- Empty: with ... prompt text and button on gray
- Not empty: content binding to data and button on black

But the above code doesn't works because `TexField` expects a non optional type.
I find a workaround for `String` types [SwiftUI Optional TextField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57021722/swiftui-optional-textfield) but doesn't apply to `Double?` because `Double` doesn't has an empty state ""

Some hint ? ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are using a `NumberFormatter`, use the newer formatting instead introduced with SwiftUI, `FormatStyle`. It will handle an optional double the way you expect it to.

```
TextField("", value: $data, format: .number, prompt:Text("..."))
```