# Error in .onAppear - Value of optional type 'String?' must be unwrapped

Tags: swiftui

I'm getting an error in SwiftUI when using the .onAppear modifier. I'm trying to unwrap and assign optional string values (name) from an optional object (item). Despite using an if let statement, I'm getting the error "Value of optional type 'String?' must be unwrapped to a value of type 'String'".
If I change:

```
@State private var name = ""
```

To

```
@State private var name: String?
```

That clears the error but then the TextField has an error "Cannot convert value of type 'Binding<String?>' to expected argument type 'Binding'" example:

```
TextField("Name", text: $name)
```

What I'm confused about is this is only an issue for optional string types and not other optional types and why it's not working even though it's wrapped in a if let statement.

In the SwiftData model, timestamp is a Date, name is a String? And priority is a Priority?

Here's the relevant .onAppear code snippet:

```
.onAppear {
    if let item {
        timestamp = item.timestamp
        name = item.name // optional String has error
        priority = item.priority // Priority() is a custom optional type but no error
    }
}
```

I am using .onAppear like this because it's how I've read it in the SwiftData Documentation,  and what's happening here is I'm passing an optional item object to a edit view and if the item exists then it will edit the item otherwise create a new one.

Comment: with `@State private var name = ""`, in .onAppear try,
 `if let item, let theName = item.name { ... name = theName ...}`

Comment: `name = item.name ?? ""` is another way

Comment: ha yes, much better.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson that's what I did initially but like I said I thought I should have been able to do without it as I used `if let`. Perhaps I'll just have to go with the nil coalescing.

Comment: I don't think you understand what `if let` does then, it unwraps `item` itself but not all the properties it contains so you either need to unwrap `name` also or supply a value if it's nil as I did.

Comment: Oh ok, thanks. Yeah I wasn't sure why the optional strings had to be unwrapped but the priority didn't eg `priority = item.priority ?? .low`

Comment: @TimD check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57021722/swiftui-optional-textfield

Answer (score 0):

Create a binding from an optional binding:

```
if let nameBinding = Binding($name) {
    TextField("Name", text: nameBinding)
}
else {
    Text("Name is null")
}
```

Or make another non-optional state like `@State var editingName = ""` and then have a button that copies from `editingName` to your optional `name`.

Either way a `TextField` needs an actual string to add/remove characters when typing, so optionality is just not compatible.

FYI, `onAppear` is for calling external actions, not updating state. I'm intrigued to learn where in the SwiftData docs you saw this bad advice.

Comment: This will crash at runtime if `name` is `nil`.

Comment: Another option (rather than just not displaying the field) is to use one of the answers found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57021722/swiftui-optional-textfield

Comment: @malhal https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftdata/adding-and-editing-persistent-data-in-your-app
I noticed the SwiftUI Optional TextField question. Looks good.

Comment: @TimD that use of onAppear is bad because if there is navigation forward and back then onAppear happens again and any edits to the states will be lost. A better place is in init where the states can be init with initial values or even better when the animal is selected in parent view.