SwiftUI TextField with Nested Optional Type
Hi everyone !
I'm using SwiftData with a View designed to update the @Model.
Here is my Data :
@Model
final class Pet {
    var name: String
    var gender: Gender
    var type: String
    var race: String
    var birthdate: Date
    var color: String
    var eyeColor: String
    var photo: Data?
    var identification: Identification?

    init(
        name: String,
        gender: Gender,
        type: String,
        race: String,
        birthdate: Date,
        color: String,
        eyeColor: String,
        photo: Data?
    ) {
        self.name = name
        self.gender = gender
        self.type = type
        self.race = race
        self.birthdate = birthdate
        self.color = color
        self.eyeColor = eyeColor
        self.photo = photo
    }
}

@Model
final class Identification {
    var chip: Int?
    var chipLocation: String?
    var tatoo: String?
    var tatooLocation: String?

    init(chip: Int?, chipLocation: String?, tatoo: String?, tatooLocation: String?) {
        self.chip = chip
        self.chipLocation = chipLocation
        self.tatoo = tatoo
        self.tatooLocation = tatooLocation
    }
}

As you can see, I have a type called Identification, nested in the Pet model, and it is optional.
Furthermore, all of its property are optional too.
I'm trying to edit the chip property in the following way :
struct EditInformationView: View {
    @Environment(Pet.self) var pet

    var body: some View {
        @Bindable var pet = pet

        Form {
            Section("Identification") {
                TextField("Chip", value: $pet.identification?.chip)
            }
        }
    }
}

My question is really simple, how can I do to edit the chip parameter with my TextField ?
I'm a bit lost here and would appreciate a little help, thanks a lot :)
I tried to to optional chaining, like Xcode suggested me but it didn't worked.

Well as you know, identification and chip can be nil. What should happen when they are nil?

You have to deal with the nested type before getting to the property. There is no way a TextField would know how to create an Identification

does this SO post/answer address your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57021722/swiftui-optional-textfield

@Sweeper if they are nil, I would have display an empty TextField with a placeholder for the user to help him fill the TextField. But I don't know how to do that using Bindable :(

@loremipsum I'd love to do it, but I don't know how by using Bindable, which gives me Bindings to the model properties.

@workingdogsupportUkraine It is useful, but in my case, I have a nested type in between and furthermore, the property is an Int? :x

You can use any of the "Optional Binding solutions"
Option 1
struct EditInformationView: View {
    @Environment(Pet.self) var pet

    var body: some View {
        @Bindable var pet = pet

        Form {
            Section("Identification") {
                if let identification = Binding($pet.identification) {
                    TextField("Chip", value: identification.chip, format: .number)
                } else {
                    ProgressView()
                        .task {
                            pet.identification = Identification(chip: nil, chipLocation: nil, tatoo: nil, tatooLocation: nil)
                        }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Option 2
struct EditInformationView: View {
    @Environment(Pet.self) var pet
    
    var body: some View {
        @Bindable var pet = pet
        
        Form {
            Section("Identification") {
                TextField("Chip", value: ($pet.identification ?? Identification(chip: nil, chipLocation: nil, tatoo: nil, tatooLocation: nil)).chip, format: .number)
                
            }
        }
    }
}

@MainActor func ?? <Element> (lhs: Binding<Element?>, rhs: Element) -> Binding<Element> {
    Binding {
        lhs.wrappedValue ?? rhs
    } set: { newValue in
        lhs.wrappedValue = newValue
    }
    
}

There are several others if you search SO.
The essence is dealing with identification before you deal with its properties. There are infinite ways of dealing with this.

Both options works like a charm, thanks a lot ! I just wanted to ask you about the .default thing, I replaced this by the Identification init(), I suppose that this is what you meant. But should I create a "default" variable in the Model and provide a default Identification ?

@Jintae that is a style thing, that is why I removed it, I have .default or .sample but it wouldn't be best with SwiftData, just an SO quick typing thing.

Oh, ok. May I ask you in what it is not best with SwiftData and should I really avoid it ?

because .default would mean that Identification has a static let \default` = Identification(). The same .defaultobject will be used everywhere you use it. Meaning that all thePetwill have the sameIdentification`. @Jintae

@Jintae you would get a new one if you use static func default() -> Identification {} but it is just as easy to use init()

Oh I see, you are completely right, I didn't see that. Thank you again, you're amazing !

You could try this simple approach using an
intermediate variable and .onSubmit,
as shown in the example code:
struct EditInformationView: View {
    @Environment(Pet.self) var pet

    @State private var chipVal = 0  // <--- here

    var body: some View {
        @Bindable var pet = pet

        Form {
            Section("Identification") {
                TextField("Chip", value: $chipVal, format: .number)  // <--- here
                    .onSubmit {
                        pet.identification?.chip = chipVal  // <--- here
                    }
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            if let chipv = pet.identification?.chip {  // <--- here
                chipVal = chipv
            }
        }
    }
}

Note, you can also use .onChange(of: chipVal)

I tried it and it worked, but when I closed EditInformationView, it does not re-render the parent view, which is : InformationView.
Let me explain.
The View Hierarchy is : PetListView -> InformationView -> EditInformationView(this one is modal).
I used your method, closed EditInformationView and the change did not propagate to InformationView, it was the older chip number.
But it did propagate on the first parent View : PetListView.
Maybe because of the "@Query var pets: [Pet]" inside ?

This does not give identification a value, the assignment will just get lost
